# How to exclude files and folders when using Fortify with MSBuild

Tags: fortify

I "translate" my sources with msbuild using the following command:

```
sourceanalyzer -b sample -exclude "**/*.xml" "**/Test/**" msbuild sample.sln /maxcpucount:1
```

After this is done I analyze the source with:

```
sourceanalyzer -b sample -scan -f result.fpr
```

The sample.sln solution contains a lot of test projects too. Those projects produce a lot of findings I’m not interested in. How can I exclude those projects? They are all in "Test" sub folders. I’ve tried the –exclude switch with no luck. I guess it is ignored when building with msbuild.

The analyzer also produces findings for xml files which comes with 3rd party libraries. This is interesting but I do not want to have them in my report. The exclude does also not work here.

Comment: What I found out so far is that the exclude pattern need to start with a fully qualified part e.g. `C:\MySources\**\*.xml`. Then it works. What does not work are patterns in folder names like `*test*`.

Answer (score 3):

### here is the official Fortify documentation (from version 17.10):

*File specifiers are expressions that allow you to pass a long list of files to Fortify Static Code Analyzer using wild card characters. Fortify Static Code Analyzer recognizes two types of wild card characters: a single asterisk character (*) matches part of a file name, and double asterisk characters (**) recursively matches directories. You can specify one or more files, one or more file specifiers, or a combination of files and file specifiers.*

```
<files> | <file specifiers>
```

*The following table describes the different file specifiers forms:*

- dirname : All files found in the named directory or any subdirectories.
- dirname/**/Example.java: Any file named Example.java found in the named directory or any subdirectories.
- dirname/*.java: Any file with the extension .java found in the named directory.
- dirname/**/*.java: Any file with the extension .java found in the named directory or any subdirectories.
- /**/*: All files found in the named directory or any subdirectories (same as ).

*Note: Windows and many Unix shells automatically expand parameters that contain the asterisk character (*), so you must enclose file-specifier expressions in quotes. Also, on Windows, you can use the backslash character () as the directory separator instead of the forward slash (/).*

### File specifiers do not apply to C, C++, or Objective-C++ languages.

According to the above documentation, you would have to pass all "Test" subfolders paths:

```
-exclude path1/**/*|path2/**/*|etc..
```

but the last documentation line is saying that it will not be supported in C/C++/ObjectiveC++.